# How can I install gcc 7.3 for ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

It looks like Jonathan F's gcc-7.3 build doesn't work for Ubuntu 16.04. amd64 build has a failed status. See [here](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.3).

At this point Ubuntu Toolchain [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) only has gcc-7.2.

Are there any relatively easy alternative ways to upgrade existing gcc to gcc 7.3?

Thanks.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gcc-7

Comment: Thanks Alex. Do I just download the .deb package and run sudo dpkg -i? Anything else I should watch out for?

Comment: I do not know the exact name of the package you need, look for an analogy https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu/download  more https://archlinux.pkgs.org/rolling/archlinux-core-x86_64/gcc-7.3.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz.html (this `sudo dpkg -i`). If `deb` package - `sudo apt install` or `Gdebi` or `Synaptic`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see detailed answers to this issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009433/dependency-issues-while-installing-gcc-7-3-from-jonathon-fs-ppa/1009438?noredirect=1).

Essentially you need to use a different ppa channel. This has worked for me for gcc 7.3 on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the new one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-8.0 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-8
```

Comment: I did this, and it broke clang. The PPA's gcc doesn't come with the c++ libraries, and there's no g++-8. kBAM!

Comment: `The user named '~jonathonf' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/gcc-8.0'`

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.3
```

is needed

Comment: `The user named '~jonathonf' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/gcc-7.3'`